# NetLogo picking specific items from turtles-own list

Tags: netlogo

My turtles have two turtle-own variables. *itm* is a numeric value between 0 and 2 and *lst* that is a list with 3 numeric items.

I now want to retrieve the *itm*th item of *lst* from all turtles and sum them.

My current approach is the following, but it yields wrong results.

```
reduce [ [foo ID] -> (item ([i] of turtle ID) ([l] of turtle ID)) + foo ] ([who] of turtles)
```

I could do it with a simple `foreach` loop but I want to have it in one line if possible.

Other approaches or correction of my approach is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Kudos for trying to use `reduce`! Your approach here is not quite right (see my answer) but your basic intuition is correct: a sum *is* a reduction. (`sum my-list` is the equivalent `reduce + my-list`.)

Comment: The reduce approach works to. A dummy has to be added to the who list `reduce [ [foo ID] -> foo + (item ([itm] of turtle ID) ([lst] of turtle ID) ) ] (fput 0 ([who] of turtles) )` but yours is much more elegant and will be used hereinafter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
sum [ item itm lst ] of turtles
```

As a more general comment: avoid trying to refer to turtles using their `who` number. It's almost never needed and is usually an indication that you're thinking the wrong way about what you're trying to accomplish...